# How to use JNDI DataSource provided by WebLogic in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, weblogic, datasource, jndi

It is said in Spring javadoc article about DriverManagerDataSource class, that this class is very simple and that it is recommended

to use a JNDI DataSource provided by the container. Such a DataSource can be exposed as a DataSource bean in a Spring ApplicationContext via JndiObjectFactoryBean

The question is: how to accomplish this?

For example if I wish to have DataSource bean to access my custo oracle database, what I require then? What to write in context configuration etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access a JNDI data source you do something like:

```
<bean id="dbDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/MyDatabase"/>
</bean>
```

or look et the spring 'jee' schema.

The details of the database connection are configured in WebLogic, the application accesses 
the database through the jndi name.

Answer (score 3):

Or use Java based configuration and do it like this:

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "")
public DataSource dataSource() throws NamingException{
    Context context = new InitialContext();
    return (DataSource)context.lookup("jdbc.mydatasource");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another option:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dbDataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/MyLocalDB"
        expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following jndi configuration.

```
<beans:bean id="weblogicDataSource" class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.JndiRmiProxyFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="jndiName" value="ConnectionPoolJNDINameAsConfigured"></beans:property>
    <beans:property name="jndiEnvironment">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="java.naming.provider.url">iiop://localhost:7001</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="serviceInterface" value="javax.sql.DataSource"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

and you make the reference to your injected class file as

```
<beans:bean id="xxxx" class="xxxxxxxx">
    <beans:property name="wlDataSource"  ref="weblogicDataSource" />
</beans:bean>
```

and in your implemenation class, use

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;
```

make an instance as
    private DataSource wlDataSource;

and corresponding setter. Now you are free to use JDBCTemplate or SimpleJDBCCall etc as per your implementation thinking.

- Hope this will help.